# What printers or methods are used to apply a matte lamination finish to the blank surface of an optical disc?

Tags: print-design, screen-printing, digital-printing

I am a print design hobbyist and I have been trying to learn about how I can print my designs onto the surface of blank optical discs with a professional  matte lamination finished style. (As shown in the Image below.)

Professional quality CDs, DVDs, Software and other optical disc media products have a smooth matte lamination style to the front surface of the discs and lately I have been wondering how it is that this style is actually produced.

Would somebody here please be able to explain to me in a reasonable amount of detail what printers, technology or methods are used to apply a matte lamination finish to the blank surface of an optical disc?

(Image shows a matte laminated disc surface which is non-gloss and non-reflective)[image]

Comment: Are you asking about factory methods (how batches of such discs are made 'en mass') or about CD-R discs with matte surface on to which design is printed with ink-jets?

Comment: I didn't notice your comment until now. I was referencing factory methods.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilites how they achieved this look and feel:

1. The foundation for the print (usually white) soaks in a lot of the color in the process. Then it was not a finishing step.
2. They have used a matte UV top coat. Then it was a (well in case of UV: two) finishing step.

But first to get a very high-quality print directly onto a blank disc you would have to choose one of the two available printing options:

1. Silkscreen
2. Offset (which is more of a "tampon-offset"/"dabber-offset")

In both case the printing machine is a special designed machine just for the purpose of printing directly onto blank dics and the white foundation/baselayer will always be printed via silkscreen method. And the look and feel depends on the foundation/base layer like in normal printing where it depends on the paper you choose. So if you have a matte foundation (or paper) and then want a glossy finish you would have to get a coating of your product in the last step. Otherwise it just stays matte. In your case, I would say it was printed via the offset-method, because in the silkscreen method a lot more printing-color is used and it would shine a little bit more.

---

More about partial offset-cd-printing in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuWMAsH9MTo)

---

More about complete silkscreen-cd-printing in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wdrjkl5GkGQ)